# Custom UIView from xib always has height of 600 pt (UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height constraint)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I'm loading a custom UIView (from a xib file) as the header view of a UITableView:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ActivityFeedHeaderView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as ActivityFeedHeaderView
}
```

But regardless of my autolayout constraints, the UIView always has a height of 600. All the subviews have height constraints and vertical space constraints, so the overall height for the UIView should be defined by this. But I get these constraint conflicts:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10c1d160 V:[UILabel:0x7fae10c39340'Something'(24)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10c4bdc0 V:[UILabel:0x7fae10c6e850'Area 31'(17)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10c59510 V:[UITableView:0x7fae11078400(308)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10c276e0 V:|-(33)-[UILabel:0x7fae10c39340'Something']   (Names: '|':Fruitful_Reports.ActivityFeedHeaderView:0x7fae10c6ed00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10c27780 V:[UILabel:0x7fae10c39340'Something']-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fae10c6e850'Area 31']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10c27870 V:[UITableView:0x7fae11078400]-(20)-|   (Names: '|':Fruitful_Reports.ActivityFeedHeaderView:0x7fae10c6ed00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10c278c0 V:[UILabel:0x7fae10c6e850'Area 31']-(24)-[UITableView:0x7fae11078400]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10f869d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[Fruitful_Reports.ActivityFeedHeaderView:0x7fae10c6ed00(600)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10c59510 V:[UITableView:0x7fae11078400(308)]>
```

The constraint I don't want is:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fae10f869d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[Fruitful_Reports.ActivityFeedHeaderView:0x7fae10c6ed00(600)]>"
```

Why is this being added by the system, and is there a way I can remove it? Cheers

**Edit:**

This constraint is added because 600 is the value I'm returning from this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    headerView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ActivityFeedHeaderView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as ActivityFeedHeaderView)

    return headerView!.frame.size.height
}
```

But I'm still wondering, how do I get the headerView to update its height based on the height and vertical space constraints of its subviews?

Comment: What is the constraints that you are setting to the view with respect to the super view?

Comment: I haven't added any constraints with respect to the superview, since I'm handing the view back to the system (i.e. I'm not adding it to any superview myself). Should I be adding constraints to the superview?

Comment: I've updated the post with some more information about where the extra constraint is coming from.

Comment: Yes You should be adding constraints with respect to super view

Comment: Try setting width and height constraint's to the xib view based on your tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was implementing:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    ...
}
```

I removed that method, and added these settings to the UITableView, and the header now displays with the correct height:

```
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 300.0
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```